# React JS + REDUX + JWT Authentication JSON issue

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, jwt

I have tried a lot to get this done but i dont know why the json is not printing on the DIV tag

*I am getting a user1 is undefined*

i am using my own api to fetch data which is populate in users.

> { success: true, user: "Normal User" }

JSON is as above

got the authorized token and logged in with it successfully but when i get the JSOn i cant show the user in the HTML page

please help!

Thanks in advance

this is my HomePage.jsx

````
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll());
    }
    render() {
        var { user, users1 } = this.props;
        console.log(user); // token
        console.log(users1); // json with names and all
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hi {users1.user} !</h1>
                <p>
                    <Link to="/login">Logout</Link>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { users, authentication } = state;
    const { user } = authentication;
    // var users1 = {"success":true,"user":"Normal User"}
    var users1 = users.users
    return {
        user,
        users1
    };
}

const connectedHomePage = connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
export { connectedHomePage as HomePage };```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't parse JSON after the fetch and *users1* in your case is a string. Try `JSON.parse(users1)`.

Comment: I did that it is in my actions.

`function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        return data;
    });
}`

Comment: Ok :) I don't know what is the structure of your store so does `state.users.users` path exist?

Comment: It automatically creates Users.users